# how do I store the HMAC key irretrievably in the database?

Tags: hash, digital-signature, salt, hmac

I'm trying to build a API service for a system that (due to many reasons) does not have the main database in a completely secured fashion.

So, my question is - how do I salt the HMAC in such a manner such that even if the main database is compromised, you still cannot use the API key. This effectively means that the HMAC key is not preshared in plaintext but in some other way, but I'm not able to figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

If your storage is insecure, you're going to have an impossible time encrypting it and still being able to decrypt it later unless you either store its encryption key somewhere (which, from your description, would still be insecure), or receive the key from the remote side of your service.